# Cucumber instantiating every Java class for each Scenario

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd

I have the following feature file where I am running two scenarios:

```
    Feature: Is it Friday yet?
  Everybody wants to know when it's Friday

  Scenario: Sunday isn't Friday
    Given today is Sunday
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet
    Then I should be told "Nope"

  Scenario: Friday is Friday
    Given today is Friday
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet
    Then I should be told "TGIF"
```

All the steps defined here are referencing one Step Definition file called - StepDefinitions.java.

There is one more Java file(let' say OtherStepDef.java) lying in the same glue folder. However, I am not referencing/calling anything in that file.
In this other file, I have put one instance block just for logging purpose that prints to console so that I know it was instantiated.

I have noticed when I execute the above feature file, which executes two Scenarios(or tests), cucumber instantiates the OtherStepDef.java file for each of the test. The log message gets printed to console even though none of the executing method in StepDefinitions.java are referencing anything in OtherStepDef.java.

Is it the expected behavior?
So, does it mean that cucumber instantiates each Java class lying in the glue folder every time a Scenario is executed regardless of whether or not it's being referenced/called or not?

[Update]: My bad. Turns out there was one @After Hook in the other step def file which made cucumber instantiate the file. After commenting out that part, it is no longer printing to console.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the expected behavior? So, does it mean that cucumber instantiates each Java class lying in the glue folder every time a Scenario is executed (...) ?

Yes, exactly.

AFAIK the main motivation for this design is to guarantee (or at least improve) the independence of scenarios: the data of one scenario cannot leak into another scenario as long as you're not using static variables.

> (...) regardless of whether or not it's being referenced/called or not ?

From your last comment it seems it's not the case: only needed classes are instantiated.

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. Actually, it doesn't. I just checked it. There was one method annotated with @After hook in the other step def file which made cucumber instantiate it. After commenting it, it longer is instantiating that class.

Comment: You mean it doesn't instantiate unnecessary classes? But still it does instantiate class at each scenario.

Comment: Slightly different use case than what is mentioned above... I'm using `cucumber-spring` with Junit5 and noticed this is exactly what was happening to me. I only have a single file for Step Definitions. My cucumber is for testing my API and in my background I get a token to be able to authenticate before actually calling my API. I don't want to do this for each Scenario as it's a waste. Once I added "static" to my variable, all good the state is preserved so I can use the same token for my tests.